# Json.NET - Custom deserialization of multiple object properties to list of single type?

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I've been trying to come up with the simplest/cleanest method for handling this and after several refactors am no closer. I am hoping someone here can assist.

The JSON returned from the service I am calling is unpredictable and constantly updates.

Example:

```
{
    SomeKey : "SomeValue",
    SecondaryProperties: {
        Property1: { "Id" : "ABC", "Label" : "Property One", "Value" : 1 },
        Property2: { "Id" : "DEF", "Label" : "Property Two", "Value" : 10 },
        Property3: { "Id" : "GHI", "Label" : "Property Three", "Value" : 5 },
        Banana: { "Id" : "YUM", "Label" : "Property Four", "Value" : 5 },
        WeJustAddedThis: { "Id" : "XYZ", "Label" : "Property Five", "Value" : 1 }
    }
}
```

Since these secondary property keys are constantly changing (note: the values are always consistent thankfully!), it makes little sense to create an object with properties for each as I'd be updating the object often and unless I was told a new data point was added to the API data, it would never appear in the application until the code was updated.

So I had a thought to create a custom attribute converter that would make a list of a `SecondaryProperty` object. Something like:

```
public class SecondaryProperties {
    public string SomeKey { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SecondaryPropertyConverter))]
    public List<SecondaryProperty> PropertyList { get; set; }
}

public class SecondaryProperty {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

// This is where things get hazy for me
public class SecondaryPropertyConverter: JsonConverter {
    ...
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        var ratings = new List<SecondaryProperty>();
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        foreach(var property in obj.Properties()){
            var rating = property.Value<SecondaryProperty>();
            ratings.Add(rating);
        }
        return ratings;
    }  
}
```

I think I'm on the right track, but the list is always null, so clearly I'm missing something. Can anyone provide some insight?

Many thanks!

Comment: See also [Handling extra members when deserializing with Json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25395765/10263)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for anything fancy, if the new items all have a consistent pattern we can do this:

```
void Main()
{
    var json=  @"{
    SomeKey : ""SomeValue"",
    SecondaryProperties: {
        Property1: { ""Id"" : ""ABC"", ""Label"" : ""Property One"", ""Value"" : 1 },
        Property2: { ""Id"" : ""DEF"", ""Label"" : ""Property Two"", ""Value"" : 10 },
        Property3: { ""Id"" : ""GHI"", ""Label"" : ""Property Three"", ""Value"" : 5 },
        Banana: { ""Id"" : ""YUM"", ""Label"" : ""Property Four"", ""Value"" : 5 },
        WeJustAddedThis: { ""Id"" : ""XYZ"", ""Label"" : ""Property Five"", ""Value"" : 1 }
    }
}"; 

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
}

public class Property
{

    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}



public class Root
{

    [JsonProperty("SomeKey")]
    public string SomeKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("SecondaryProperties")]
    public Dictionary<string, Property> SecondaryProperties { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Sample response]

Comment: Nothing wrong with simple vs fancy. This answer just goes to show that I am indeed probably over thinking things. Much appreciated.