# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject not converting a response object from JSON as expected

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I am creating an ActiveCampaign V1.1 wrapper for C#.NET and creating a class that lists the ContactLists using (https://www.activecampaign.com/api/example.php?call=list_list)

The response object returned after `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BasicListResponse>(JSON)` does have non-list properties populated, but the list portion of the JSON is not converted.

I have tried the following `BasicListResponse` implementations:

```
public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("result_code")]
    public int ResultCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("result_message")]
    public string ResultMessage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("result_output")]
    public string ResultOutput { get; set; }
}

public class BasicListResponse : Result
{      
    public Dictionary<string, BasicList> list { get; set; }
}

public class BasicList
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cdate")]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("private")]
    public bool Private { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userid")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("subscriber_count")]
    public int SubscriberCount { get; set; }
}
```

I have also tried to use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) or VS > Paste Special but the output has numbered classes rather than a list of objects.

The JSON response is as follows:

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx",
        "cdate": "2019-10-27 22:43:23",
        "private": "0",
        "userid": "1",
        "subscriber_count": 1
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "yyyyy yyyyy yyyyy",
        "cdate": "2019-10-27 22:44:03",
        "private": "0",
        "userid": "1",
        "subscriber_count": 0
    },
    "result_code": 1,
    "result_message": "Success: Something is returned",
    "result_output": "json"
}
```

I extracted the `Dictionary<T,T>` in the wrapper but the list is always NULL.

If I re-serialize the `BasicListResponse` the results are as follows

`{ "list": null, "result_code": 1, "result_message": "Success: Something is returned", "result_output": "json" }`

I expect the `BasicListResponse` to be used as a root object containing a List/Array with three string `result_*` properties.

I appreciate any help to resolve this.

Comment: JSON object doesn't contain `list`. Perhaps you need [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395765/handling-extra-members-when-deserializing-with-json-net)?

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp try this to get proper class structure matching your JSON

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling extra members when deserializing with Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395765/handling-extra-members-when-deserializing-with-json-net)

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eSLWpe

Comment: Try deserializing directly to `Dictionary<string, BasicList>`.

Comment: @john - that question was helpful too. @rahul-sharma - Your solution was working but I went for @brian-rodgers because I inclined towards conversion to `List<T>` directly rather than `dynamic`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON basically represents a dictionary of `string`-`BasicList` pairs, comingled with some other properties about the overall result.  This format makes it more difficult to work with.  (It would have been better if the dictionary data were in child object in the JSON.)

The easiest way to handle this situation is to take advantage of Json.Net's "[Extension Data](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm#JsonExtensionDataAttribute)" feature.

Here's what you would need to do:

1. Create a private `Dictionary<string, JToken>` property in your `BasicListResponse` class and mark it with the `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute.  This will catch the dictionary data during deserialization.
2. Change your `list` property be a  `List<BasicList>` instead of a `Dictionary<string, BasicList>`.  (I would also rename it with proper capitalization to be consistent with your other properties.)
3. Add a private `OnDeserialized` method as shown below to populate the `List<BasicList>` from the extension dictionary at the end of the deserialization process.

So your `BasicListResponse` class should look like this:

```
public class BasicListResponse : Result
{
    public List<BasicList> List { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    private Dictionary<string, JToken> Data { get; set; }

    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        List = Data?.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
                    .Select(kvp => kvp.Value.ToObject<BasicList>())
                    .ToList();
    }
}
```

There is one other small problem we need to address: in your `BasicList` class you have defined the `Private` property as `bool`, but in the JSON it is a string containing a number.  This will cause deserialization to fail due to incompatible types.  To make it work, you can either change `Private` to be a string and then handle the interpretation of the value elsewhere in your code, or you can do something like this:

```
public class BasicList
{
    ...

    [JsonProperty("private")]
    private string PrivateAsString { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool Private
    {
        get { return PrivateAsString != "0"; }
        set { PrivateAsString = value ? "1" : "0"; }
    }

    ...
}
```

With these changes you can deserialize to your `BasicListResponse` class and everything should work properly.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BasicListResponse>(json);
```

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9MmSuG

Comment: Rodgers - I am going to give it go

Comment: Rodgers, the solution worked. Thanks for the help.` [JsonExtensionData]` is going to be a great tool because I am dealing with a lot of JSON that is not following a good structure.

Comment: No problem; I'm glad you found the solution useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but you could structure your classes like this:

```
public class Results
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public IDictionary<string, JToken> Items;

    [JsonProperty("result_code")]
    public long ResultCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("result_message")]
    public string ResultMessage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("result_output")]
    public string ResultOutput { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Cdate { get; set; }

    public long Private { get; set; }

    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public long SubscriberCount { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Id={Id},Name={Name},CDate={Cdate.ToString()},Private={Private},UserId={UserId},SubscriberCount={SubscriberCount}";
    }
}
```

Then you could deserialize your json and map your `IDictionary<string, JToken> Items` to a `IEnumerable<Result>`. Note that `JsonExtensionData` needs to be `IDictionary<string, JToken>` in this case.

```
var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Results>(json);

var results = deserializedJson
    .Items
    .Select(entry => new Result
    {
        Id = (long)entry.Value["id"],
        Name = (string)entry.Value["name"],
        Cdate = DateTime.TryParse((string)entry.Value["cdate"], out var cdate) ? cdate : DateTime.MinValue,
        Private = (long)entry.Value["private"],
        UserId = (long)entry.Value["userid"],
        SubscriberCount = (long)entry.Value["subscriber_count"]
    });

Console.WriteLine($"result_code={deserializedJson.ResultCode},result_message={deserializedJson.ResultMessage},result_output={deserializedJson.ResultOutput}");
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
}
```

Output:

```
result_code=1,result_message=Success: Something is returned,result_output=json
Id=1,Name=xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx,CDate=27/10/2019 10:43:23 PM,Private=0,UserId=1,SubscriberCount=1
Id=2,Name=yyyyy yyyyy yyyyy,CDate=27/10/2019 10:44:03 PM,Private=0,UserId=1,SubscriberCount=0
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
"list":{
    "0": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx",
        "cdate": "2019-10-27 22:43:23",
        "private": "0",
        "userid": "1",
        "subscriber_count": 1
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "yyyyy yyyyy yyyyy",
        "cdate": "2019-10-27 22:44:03",
        "private": "0",
        "userid": "1",
        "subscriber_count": 0
    },
    "result_code": 1,
    "result_message": "Success: Something is returned",
    "result_output": "json"
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the OP's issue.  The JSON is coming from a third party.

Comment: @shan, would not take the JSON manipulation path to solve the problem. The JSON received is fixed.